# Dequeue script to prevent javascript event conflict on wordpress child theme

Tags: functions, ajax, javascript, child-theme, buddypress

I've built a child theme of [Divi Theme](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) to use with [Buddypress](https://buddypress.org/). So far so good, except for a script conflict on commenting buttons.

The theme load a javascript (`js/custom.js` at 2642:2662) with the following function:

```
    $( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).click( function() {
        if ( $(this).closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $(this).closest( '.tabs' ).length ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) {
            var target = $( this.hash );
            target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']' );
            if ( target.length ) {
                et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 800 );

                if ( ! $( '#main-header' ).hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' ) && $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'et_fixed_nav' ) && $( window ).width() > 980 ) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 200);
                    }, 500 );
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

This event target the same button that Buddypress use for commenting, preventing AJAX form from loading on click.

[image]

I don't want to edit the parent theme (custom.js). How can I prevent this conflict? Is there a workaround, maybe from **functions.php**?

**UPDATE**

Using [wp_dequeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) to load that script later, didn't work. When using this code in functions.php

```
function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'divi-custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );
```

then the full script (custom.js) was not loaded at all.

Comment: why is this a wordpress specific question?

Comment: I'm trying to build a child theme for wordpress. Maybe should be more generic? Something like "how to unbind a specific piece of javascript loaded from the parent theme, when developing a child theme".

Comment: exactly, it is a question about conflict resolution between two JS libraries, whatever is the solution it will have very little to do with wordpress unless your question is how to enqueue and dequeue JS files.

Comment: It is a question on how to handle conflict between javascript when developing child themes on wordpress. Sorry but I'm missing your point. Do you think the question should be edited? How?

Comment: there is no general conflict handling and each conflict has it own resolution. Once you know what type of resolution will work for you people can help you to implement it in the context of wordpress but for that first step you need JS experts not wordpress experts.

Comment: To this, I might add, this has nothing to do with parent and child themes. This is about what to do when js library loaded before your own that you have no control on, interferes with what you want to do. This is not a WordPress question. @Giulio, if you ask this on Stack overflow and tag it with jQuery and paste the link in the commnents here, I promise I'll give you the answer. I have done this before.

Comment: And yes, I've done this with BuddyPress and [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-media/) that I've built in the past.

Comment: Lat one, because I couldn't resist it, you should ask for a refund from the theme guys just for using the `$(selector).click()` instead of on and off. (there's your answer)

Comment: @MarkKaplun ok thanks, I was hoping to find both here ;)

Comment: @SaurabhShukla before posting here I posted the same question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782415/resolve-javascript-conflict-with-parent-theme-on-wordpress-child-theme but it happen I found my own solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to resolve the javascript conflict I've set up a simple `tl_custom.js` under my theme `js/` folder, with the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //  Remove handler set by themes/Divi/js/custom.js at line 2642
    $( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).off();
});
```

Then I add the script with the following code in `functions.php`

```
function tl_custom_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/';
        wp_register_script( 'tl_custom', $scriptsrc . 'tl_custom.js', '', '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tl_custom' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tl_custom_scripts', 20 );
```

The main problem is that the parent theme register `custom.js` in the footer, so I had to set the [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) last parameter to `true` and then set [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) priority to 20.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem with my premium theme not having buddypress support. Disabling the click event removes the ability to have scrollto page anchors which I have on one of my interior pages. So I just target the buddypress class to enable the comment/reply buttons.

```
if ( $('body').hasClass('buddypress') ) {

    $( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).off();

}
```

I placed the code in a custom.js file in my child theme then enqueued the resource from functions.php. Make sure the file is enqueued after the premium theme's js.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely WordPress perspective, the only solution I see would be to copy the script to your child theme and make edits to it to remove the conflict. If the parent theme uses `get_template_directory_uri` to reference the path to the script, you'll also have to dequeue the original, and enqueue your modified version. If the script is loaded using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`, then simply mirroring the same hierarchy in your child theme will correctly override the script without having to do anything else.

Of course, the issue will be with parent theme updates adding or modifying that script file, you will have to monitor each update to insure your updated theme is not broken or missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off track here, but would removing the `return false;` from the javascript you posted help?

`return false;` in a click function is like saying:

```
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
```

I think this is why your other function is not firing as there is no restriction to having multiple handlers bound to the same event on an element.  However removing the `return false;` may cause you other issues.